# How would you insert one node into another at the treepath?

Tags: java, swing

I have two nodes and one TreePath in Java Swing.
One node contains the 'root' node (let's call this nodeA), it contains everything under it .
 The second node is the 'new' Node (let's call this nodeB), it contains a new node.
I have a TreePath that shows where I want to insert nodeB in nodeA. I am trying to develop a function to do this. Any help?
Thanks in advance!

```
Node A   
 ~
      Documents
         -- text1.txt
         -- text2.txt
      Pictures
         - text1.txt
```

I want to insert the below node into the Pictures folder

```
folder1
   -- newtext1.txt
```

My insertNodes function:

```
private static void insertNodes
        (DefaultMutableTreeNode root
            ,DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode
                ,String tp)
{
    String[] elements = tp.split("/");
    String treePath = "";
    for (int i=0; i<elements.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (i == elements.length-2)
        {
            treePath += elements[i];
        } else {
        treePath += elements[i] + "/" ;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("TreePath : " + treePath);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = buildNodeFromString(treePath);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode lastLeaf = node.getLastLeaf();
    TreePath path = new TreePath(lastLeaf.getPath());
    System.out.println("insertNodes-Path =" + path);
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);



    DefaultMutableTreeNode pictureNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
    pictureNode.add(newNode);





    // Notify the model of the changes
    model.nodesWereInserted(pictureNode, new int[]{pictureNode.getChildCount() - 1});

    // The above way (you suggested) wipes out everything and just puts one "~" in the JTree


    // The below line adds them all to the "~" direcotry
    //root.add(newNode); 


}
```

My getFileStructure (where I call insertNodes)

```
    public static DefaultMutableTreeNode getFileStructure(FTPClient client,String workingPath,DefaultMutableTreeNode style )
{

try {
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Working Path: " + workingPath);
    FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(workingPath);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = buildNodeFromString(workingPath);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode lastLeaf = node.getLastLeaf();
    TreePath path = new TreePath(lastLeaf.getPath());
    System.out.println("Path =" + path);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)(path.getLastPathComponent());       
    System.out.println("Add to Node:" + selectedNode.toString());
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            // DefaultMutableTreeNode fileDirectory =new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
            // selectedNode.add(fileDirectory);

            System.out.println("\t Folder Name: " + file.getName());
            getFileStructure(client, workingPath + "/" + file.getName(),style);
        } else {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root =new DefaultMutableTreeNode();  
        System.out.println("Filename: " + file.getName());

        DefaultMutableTreeNode fileDirectory =new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());


        selectedNode.add(fileDirectory);

        System.out.println("Added to node = " + selectedNode.toString());
        System.out.println("First Node = " + selectedNode.getFirstChild().toString());
        System.out.println("Last Node = " + selectedNode.getLastChild().toString());
        System.out.println("Num of Children = " + selectedNode.getLeafCount());
        System.out.println("Depth Count= " + selectedNode.getDepth());
        }
    }
    insertNodes(style,selectedNode,workingPath);        
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("IOException:" + ex);
 } 



 return style;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, some assumptions, lets assume you have a `TreeModel` which looks something like this...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("~");
DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

DefaultMutableTreeNode docs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Documents");
docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text2.txt"));
root.add(docs);

DefaultMutableTreeNode pics = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pictures");
pics.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
root.add(pics);
```

This will generate a tree which looks something like...

```
+ ~
  + Documents
    - text1.txt
    - text2.txt
  + Pictures
    - text1.txt
```

Then, lets assume you know want to add...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode newFolder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("folder1");
newFolder.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
```

to `~/Pictures`.

Assuming you have a valid `TreePath` off `[~, Pictures]`, you can simply get the `lastComponent` from the path, which will be a reference to the `Pictures` `TreeNode`, then you can simply do something like...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode pictureNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treePathFromPicturesToRoot.getLastPathComponent();
pictureNode.add(newFolder);

// Notify the model of the changes
model.nodesWereInserted(pictureNode, new int[]{pictureNode.getChildCount() - 1});
```

which will generate a tree like...

```
+ ~
  + Documents
    - text1.txt
    - text2.txt
  + Pictures
    - text1.txt
    + folder1
      - text1.txt
```

Now, I don't know where you `TreePath` is coming from, but I assume it's a valid path made up of the nodes which are actually in the `TreeModel`, otherwise this won't work very well

Now, this based on a number of examples, if this doesn't meet your needs, then you will need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from which we can better understand you issue

## Sample code...

I built the basic concept from using the following code

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("~");
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode docs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Documents");
        docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
        docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text2.txt"));
        root.add(docs);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode pics = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pictures");
        pics.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
        root.add(pics);

        describe(model);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode newFolder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("folder1");
        newFolder.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));

        TreeNode[] pathToRoot = pics.getPath();
        TreePath treePathFromPicturesToRoot = new TreePath(pathToRoot);
        System.out.println(treePathFromPicturesToRoot);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode pictureNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treePathFromPicturesToRoot.getLastPathComponent();
        pictureNode.add(newFolder);

        model.nodesWereInserted(pictureNode, new int[]{pictureNode.getChildCount() - 1});

        describe(model);
    }

    protected static void describe(DefaultTreeModel model) {
        describe((DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot(), 0);
    }

    protected static void describe(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, int level) {
        StringBuilder padding = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < level; index++) {
            padding.append("  ");
        }
        System.out.println(padding + "+ " + node);
        padding.append("  ");
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (childNode.isLeaf()) {
                System.out.println(padding + "- " + childNode);
            } else {
                describe(childNode, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Updated based on additional code...

Your insert method should be just about as simple as...

```
private static void insertNodes(
        DefaultTreeModel model,
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent,
        DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode) {

    parent.add(newNode);
    model.nodesWereInserted(parent, new int[]{parent.getChildCount() - 1});
}
```

To find a node based on a `String` path, you "might" be able to do something like...

```
protected static DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(DefaultTreeModel model, String path) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
    String[] parts = path.split("/");
    if (node.getUserObject().toString().equals(parts[0])) {
         return findNode(node, Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length));
    }
    return null;
}

protected static DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String[] path) {
    if (path.length == 0) {
        return node;
    }
    Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)children.nextElement();
        if (child.getUserObject().toString().equals(path[0])) {
            return findNode(node, Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which means that, based on my previous example, you could do something like...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode newFolder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("folder1");
newFolder.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));

insertNodes(model, findNode(model, "~/Pictures"), newFolder);
```

## Sample #2

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("~");
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode docs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Documents");
        docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
        docs.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text2.txt"));
        root.add(docs);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode pics = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pictures");
        pics.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));
        root.add(pics);

        describe(model);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode newFolder = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("folder1");
        newFolder.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("text1.txt"));

        insertNodes(model, findNode(model, "~/Pictures"), newFolder);

        describe(model);
    }

    protected static DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(DefaultTreeModel model, String path) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
        String[] parts = path.split("/");
        if (node.getUserObject().toString().equals(parts[0])) {
            return findNode(node, Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length));
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected static DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String[] path) {
        if (path.length == 0) {
            return node;
        }
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (child.getUserObject().toString().equals(path[0])) {
                return findNode(child, Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void insertNodes(
            DefaultTreeModel model,
            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent,
            DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode) {

        parent.add(newNode);
        model.nodesWereInserted(parent, new int[]{parent.getChildCount() - 1});
    }

    protected static void describe(DefaultTreeModel model) {
        describe((DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot(), 0);
    }

    protected static void describe(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, int level) {
        StringBuilder padding = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < level; index++) {
            padding.append("  ");
        }
        System.out.println(padding + "+ " + node);
        padding.append("  ");
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (childNode.isLeaf()) {
                System.out.println(padding + "- " + childNode);
            } else {
                describe(childNode, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So @MadProgrammer thanks for the code, i appreciate it, but that seems to not work, I will provide you with more information, I will update my code to reflect the function I used to insert nodes

Comment: Since my code demonstrably works - you must provide a complete and runnable example, otherwise we will continue to go around in in guessing circles which is just going to waste each other’s time

Comment: hmm ok Can I link you a github file? It has the full code?

Comment: No, read and understand  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - this is a common requirement to 1- help people understand your code and your issue and 2- Help the community gauge the value of supplied answers

Comment: Ok. I updated my code to iinclude the function where I call insertNodes() it';s not reproducable without my GUI functions, but since you only want the core functionality of the function i updated my question with that

Comment: My personal feeling is, change `String tp` for the actually node you want to insert into.  This "seems" to be the core of your issue. Also, `DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);` is pointless as it has nothing to do with the `JTree`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186439/discussion-between-jewstin-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: So my question is you say to change the "String tp" into the node i want to insert into, but isnt that the point of the insertNodes() function ?

Comment: I've updated the my code example to provide "a" method for finding a node based on the a path and then to insert a new node into.  It makes a bunch of assumptions about the node's `userObject`, but it wouldn't be hard to modify based on your needs

Comment: I get an error: "Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at client.insertNodes(client.java:312)" I think the findNode function that parses the path returns null

Comment: Yes, it will do that if it can't find a node matching the specified path. Run the example code, see how it works and see how you might adapt the idea to your needs

Comment: Hey so I ran your example, and it adds a "folder1" to the "~" node, i wanted to add it to a folder in your case Pictures

Comment: That was there to test you ... that's my excuse and I'm sticking to it . I've updated it

Comment: Hahhahah! I like it, i like the test !